# Footer tag getting hidden in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have a footer created using the following code.
But, for some reason, the footer is sticking to the bottom.
So, whenever I shrink the size of my browser or view on a mobile device, instead of the content pushing the footer down, the content just goes over the footer.
Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there something I have to change because I'm using Bootstrap?

```css
.footer-dark {
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #f0f9ff;
  background-color: #1b1b22;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.footer-dark h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.footer-dark ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-dark ul a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.footer-dark ul a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item:not(.social) {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.footer-dark .item.text {
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item.text {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.footer-dark .item.text p {
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer-dark .item.social {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .footer-dark .item.social {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

.footer-dark .item.social > a {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  margin: 0 8px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.footer-dark .item.social > a:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.footer-dark .copyright {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 24px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .animate {
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-name: slideIn;
}

.dropdown-item:hover, .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #504fe1;
}

.navigation-clean {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .navigation-clean {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #222;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-brand img {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-toggler:hover, .navigation-clean .navbar-toggler:focus {
  background: none;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #555;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-toggler {
  color: #888;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  color: #eee;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-collapse, .navigation-clean .form-inline {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse, .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .form-inline {
  border-top-color: #333;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navigation-clean .navbar-nav > .show > a {
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navigation-clean.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active:focus, .navigation-clean.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active:hover {
  color: #8f8f8f;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #465765;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navigation-clean.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #37434d !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation-clean .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .navigation-clean .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .navigation-clean .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #37434d;
    padding-top: .8rem;
    padding-bottom: .8rem;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}

.navigation-clean .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus, .navigation-clean .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  line-height: 2;
  color: #37434d;
}

.navigation-clean .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus, .navigation-clean .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark {
  background-color: #1f2021;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav a.active, .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav a.active:focus, .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav a.active:hover {
  color: #8f8f8f;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #dfe8ee;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #1f2021;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus, .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #f2f5f8;
}

.navigation-clean.navbar-dark .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus, .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  background: #363739;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .navigation-clean.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #fff;
  }
}

#hero-logo {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #504fe1;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.49);
  padding: 17px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.07);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1b1b22;
}

.color-pallete {
  color: #c7c6c9;
  color: #1a1b21;
  color: #504fe1;
  color: #707174;
  color: #3c9dd1;
  color: #45464a;
  color: #383d6a;
  color: #335f7a;
  color: #2a3d48;
  color: #262a49;
  background-color: #1b1b22;
}

.navbar.navbar-light.navbar-expand-md {
  padding: 55px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: #504fe1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.18);
}

.navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
}

#hero-search {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#hero-search .form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

.form-control:focus {
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #739ac2;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(55,90,127,0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(55,90,127,0);
}

.text-muted.card-subtitle.mb-2 {
}

h5, .h5 {
  color: #504fe1;
}

a {
  color: #504fe1;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover {
  color: #504fe1;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#results .row {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.modal-open {
  overflow: inherit;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #222;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #504fe1;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.modal {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.pwnLogo.large {
  width: 115px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.pwnlogo {
  width: 10px;
}

.spinner-border.preloader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  border: 0.25em solid #504fe1;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>BreachDirectory.tk</title>
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="description" content="BreachDirectory.tk allows you to search through all public data breaches to make sure your emails, usernames, passwords, and domains haven&#39;t been compromised." />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="logo.png" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="logo.png" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="BreachDirectory.tk" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="BreachDirectory.tk allows you to search through all public data breaches to make sure your emails, usernames, passwords, and domains haven&#39;t been compromised." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Da" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Footer-Dark.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Navigation-Clean.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="password-meter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Team-Boxed.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <section id="hero" style="height: 100vh;width: 100vw;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-xl">
            <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand text-monospace" id="hero-logo" href="/"><img class="img-fluid" style="width: 35px;height: 35px;" src="logo.png" /><strong>  BreachDirectory.tk</strong></a><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" class="navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div
                    class="collapse navbar-collapse border-primary" id="navcol-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="notify" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notifyme" href="temp">Notify Me</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="notify" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#domain-search" href="temp">Domain</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#">Password Lookup</a>
                            <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu animate slideIn"><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="passwords.html">Password Lookup</a><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#password-toolkit">Password Strength Report</a></div>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="notify" href="breachedsources.html">Breached Sources</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="apidocs">API</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                            <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu animate slideIn"><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="about.html">About Us</a><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="privacy.html">Privacy</a><a role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQs</a>
                                <a
                                    role="presentation" class="dropdown-item" href="pastes.html">Pastes</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container text-monospace text-center" style="margin: 79px auto;">
            <div class="caption v-middle text-center">
                <h1 class="cd-headline clip"><span class="blc">Cloud Based Security </span><span class="cd-words-wrapper"><b class="is-visible">Fast</b><b>Free</b></span></h1>
            </div>
            <h1 style="font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;">Submit A Free Personal Lookup</h1>
            <h5 class="text-capitalize" style="font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;">find out if your username or email was exposed in a databreach</h5><br /></div>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="hero-search" class="shadow" style="margin: 0 auto;" onsubmit="return s()">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="term" placeholder="Enter Your Email or Username" style="margin: auto auto;border-radius: 40px;font-size: 20px;" name="term" required />
                    <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" type="submit" style="margin: 5px 5px;border-radius: 40px;font-size: 17px;background-color: #504fe1;"><i class="icon ion-search"></i></button></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><br /><br />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h3>780 Million</h3>
                    <h5>Passwords</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h3>9 Billion</h3>
                    <h5>Emails</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h3>8 Billion</h3>
                    <h5>Usernames</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h3>500+</h3>
                    <h5>Websites</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h3>10 Million</h3>
                    <h5>Pastes</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h3>1.5 Billion</h3>
                    <h5>Paste Accounts</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br /><br />
        <div class="container" id="results" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card shadow">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Passwords</h4>
                            <h6 class="text-muted card-subtitle mb-2">Censored Plaintext<br /></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div><br /></div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card shadow">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Passwords Hashed</h4>
                            <h6 class="text-muted card-subtitle mb-2">MD5 Hashes of Complete Passwords<br /></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div><br /></div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card shadow">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Sources</h4>
                            <h6 class="text-muted card-subtitle mb-2">Where The Data is From<br /></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div><br /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="footer-dark" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
                        <h3>Developers</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">API Key</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">QuickStart</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">API Docs</a></li>
                        </ul><br />
                        <h3>Individuals</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="passwords.html#hero">Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="breachedsources.html">Breached Sites</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notifyme">Get Notified</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Password Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#password-toolkit">Password Strength</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#domain-search">Domain Search</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
                        <h3>About</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html#team">Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pastes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 item text">
                        <h3><img class="img-fluid" src="logo.png" style="width: 35px;" /> BreachDirectory.tk</h3>
                        <p>BreachDirectory.tk allows you to search through all public data breaches to make sure your emails, usernames, passwords, and domains haven&#39;t been compromised.</p><br />
                        <p>For questions, to report a bug, or to request an API key, contact us at <a href="mailto:rohanpatra2003@gmail.com">rohanpatra2003@gmail.com</a>.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col item social"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i></a></div>
                </div>
                <p class="copyright">Rohan Patra - BreachDirectory.tk © 2019-2020</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I do "Run code snippet" to see an example, the footer is at the very bottom of your content. I suspect you'll need to change the path to `bootstrap.css` to a hosted one, e.g. `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: The problem isn't the footer. The problem is that `hero` has `height: 100vh`.

Comment: Good spot. Removing that'll do the job. https://codepen.io/philgyford/pen/XWmZROJ

Comment: The answer suggested by Gabriel worked, but if I remove the 100vh, how do I make the section take up the whole screen, but still allow people to scroll down and see the footer? I tried setting the height to 100%, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gabriel pointed out in the comment, it's the `#hero` element having `height:100vh` that causes the problem. At narrow widths the content of that element takes up more space than 100% of the screen's height, so it overflows the size of the element, therefore overlapping with the footer.

So there are two ways to fix it:

1. Add styles that only take effect at narrow widths, that reduce the size of some/all of the text within `#hero` so that it no longer overflows. For example, this will make the `h1` smaller when the viewport is 480px wide or narrower:

   ```css
   @media (max-width: 480px) {
     #hero h1 {
       font-size: 1.5rem;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Instead of setting `#hero` to have `height:100vh` use `min-height:100vh` ([here's the CodePen showing that](https://codepen.io/philgyford/pen/XWmZROJ)) This means that it may extend off the bottom of the screen if its content takes up too much space (i.e. at narrow widths), but it will no longer overlap the footer.

Which to choose depends on how important it is to have all of `#hero` on screen at narrow widths, whether you can fit all the text in and have it still be big enough to read, and how much CSS work you want to do.

Comment: @RohanPatra Good to hear! It's a good idea to mark a correct answer as correct, so it's clear this question has been answered.